# How to test custom URL scheme in android

Tags: android, url-scheme

I'm working on app that requires Custom URL Scheme looks like "appname://"

I've searched lot of things and also found many related questions, but I'm still having trouble.

How I can test this URL Scheme from a browser? Currently, whenever I type in a browser's address bar "appname://", it goest directly to a Google search.

I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
         <data android:scheme="appname"
             android:host="appnamehost"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is easy via adb. Check this command:

```bash
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "appname://appnamehost" your.package.name
```

However you should use your package name as schema. So you can be absolutely sure that there is no conflict (or in detail a intent chooser).

If you have multiple devices you need to execute `adb devices`. This will result a output like this:

```
List of devices attached
1645e1d0b86b    device
S9WM00904386    device
```

Then you can use that id from above to address a concrete device with the `-s` parameter. This will result a command line like this:

```bash
adb -s S9WM00904386 shell [...]
```

In case of a browser link this is also easy. You just need to add this line of html:

```
<a href="appname://appnamehost">Click me</a>
```

If you want a fallback in your url you could try the intent url:

```
<a href="intent://apphostname#Intent;scheme=appname;package=your.package.name;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com;end">with alternative</a>
```

This will open your app even if you schema is not unique, and if you app is not installed it will open example.com.

Comment: Thanks for  answer Rekine, I really appreciate it...I know how to test it by command line and I did this already and working fine, I need to know if I can directly test it from browser, Also you are right about custom scheme name, I just provided example here, real scheme is my bundle id :) , Let me know if you know how to test it directly on browser.

Comment: even, by command line, it works for jelly bean but not working for lolipop

Comment: where  I can add this href line ? it would be better if you can post some code snippet here.

Comment: Thank you Rekire, By making html from jsfiddle and run on mobile brower, it's working fine. :)

Comment: Can I get the link to JSfiddle ? I'm not seeing it in the comments.

Comment: @Vasanth there is no link. How should I guess your app schema url? You need to adapt the two html links as you need it.