# Launch Xamarin Android App Via a Browser Using Custom URL Scheme

Tags: xamarin.android, deep-linking, intentfilter, url-scheme, applinks

### Procedure

I have a cross-platform Xamarin project that needs a URL scheme. To enable this feature on Xamarin Android, I add following code in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, referenced to [launch custom android application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2958701/9512497) post.

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="urlschemetest" android:host="testurl" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Typing `urlschemetest://testurl` directly to a browser in an Android would go to Google search instead of launching the app. So, I have a simple `html` page that has a hyperlink to open the app, [test url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876003/how-to-test-custom-url-scheme-in-android).

```html
<a href="urlschemetest://testurl">open app</a>
```

### Problem

By clicking on the hyperlink above, the app isn't launched. Visual Studio shows a `Unhandled Exception` error in the Output

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest/com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.companyname.UrlSchemeTest-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

### Attempted Solutions

1) I looked at *attributes* in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and maybe it's because **package** attribute did not match with **namespace** used in `MainActivity.cs`. So I changed it.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:versionCode="1" 
   android:versionName="1.0" 
   package="UrlSchemeTest.Droid" 
   android:installLocation="auto">
```

MainActivity.cs

```cs
namespace UrlSchemeTest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "UrlSchemeTest", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", 
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, 
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity :global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
         //body here
    }
}
```

2) Using absolute classname in `<activity>` tag

```xml
<activity android:name="UrlSchemeTest.Droid.MainActivity">
```

3) To see if this was a emulator bug, I've tested the app on both Android emulator and real Android device.

**Note:** This question is about making it work on Android platform although I've created this [Xamarin simple demo](https://github.com/PhuongDTran/UrlSchemeTest) on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Explanation

Initially, I thought that the activity name is a combination of the namespace (or package name) and the class name. It's true with native Android and prior to Xamarin Android 5.1. It's not true with Xamarin Android 5.1 and later, as stated in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest)

> Beginning with Xamarin.Android 5.1, the type name of an activity is based on the MD5SUM of the assembly-qualified name of the type being exported.

With my [Xamarin simple demo](https://github.com/PhuongDTran/UrlSchemeTest) app, if you build it and open `AndroidManifest.xml` file in **UrlSchemeTest.Android/obj/Debug/android** folder, you would see something as below

```xml
<activity 
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="UrlSchemeTest" 
    android:theme="@style/MainTheme" 
    android:name="md56cd34387ec86a2e1e9ba0754e1c30e2c.MainActivity">
```

As you can see, the activity name is a combination of md5 sum and class name.

For this reason, there my had a conflict at build time when I created an activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

#### Solution

First, I need to **remove the activity** in `AndroidManifest.xml`. In the demo, following code needs to be deleted

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="urlschemetest" android:host="testurl" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then, **add** a `IntentFilter` property in `MainActivity.cs`

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;

[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "urlschemetest",
    DataHost = "testurl")]
public class MainActivity :global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Url Scheme should work now.

As an advice, I think we should try not to modify `AndroidManifest.xml` if we can.

> Xamarin.Android helps to minimize this difficulty by allowing you to add custom attributes to your classes, which will then be used to automatically generate the manifest for you. Our goal is that 99% of our users should never need to manually modify AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Hi, is "urlschemetest" still scheme working? In my case nothing detect schema as link for app, its only working with https and http scheme.

Comment: so the link to open the app should be urlschemetest://testurl correct?

Comment: Men, i have to thank you so much, i've been struggling with a similar situation and i don't know why your question and answer was so clear to me. Thanks from the heart.